# How Do I change Default Wine Browser to Native Ubuntu Browser instead of IE?

Tags: wine

I am running Wine 1.6.2 for use with Evernote. Some of my notes have links in them and by default they are launched using the Wine version of IE. I'd rather use my native browser(s) Firefox or Chrome. How does one change it so that links are opened instead by my local browsers?

Answer (score 7):

1. `wine regedit`

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Wine
- Create **WineBrowser** key if it doesn't exist
- Create **Browser** string if it doesn't exist under WineBrowser
- Edit **Browser** string to read the following

  - `xdg-open,firefox,konqueror,mozilla,netscape,galeon,opera,dillo`
- Save in `regedit`

2. `wine regedit`

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> http -> shell -> open
- Create/Edit **command** key to read the following

  - `C:\windows\system32\winebrowser.exe -nohome "%1"`
- Save in `regedit`

3. Completely close out of Wine and reload Wine.

---

#### Summary

Here, we are setting `xdg-open` to be the first *Browser*, and then changing the behaviour of *command* by adding `"%1"` as an argument.  *Be sure to perform step #2 for both `http` and `https` to support both protocols*, as mentioned in comments below.

Comment: Note to others, this works for http but the change in step two needs to be repeated for https

Comment: Do you create the Browser key inside the Wine key or the WineBrowser key?

Comment: The Browser "key" is not a key but a "string".